# Don't include variable in SQL WHERE clause if it is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, search

I have a query in SQL and currently if all of the values that the user enters in a textbox are null, when they click search it would just return the whole table.

```
SELECT Column Names
FROM TableName
WHERE
        FirstName LIKE '%' + @FirstName + '%'
        OR Surname LIKE '%' + @Surname + '%'
        OR City LIKE '%' + @City + '%'
        OR County LIKE '%' + @County + '%'
```

However, what I want to do is to not include for example `FirstName` if nothing is entered when searching. So if someone decided to enter "`London`" into `City` then it would return only those results that contained London. Likewise, if they entered "`John`" and "`London`" then I would like everyone called John in London to be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other answers are correct but I thought i'd help by putting something back into your original query:

```
 SELECT Column Names
FROM TableName
WHERE
  ((@FirstName is null and FirstName like '%') or (isnull(FirstName ,0) = @FirstName)) and
  ((@Surname is null and Surname like '%') or (isnull(Surname ,0) = @Surname)) and
  ((@City is null and City like '%') or (isnull(City ,0) = @City)) and
  ((@County is null and County like '%') or (isnull(County,0) = @County))
```

You should just be able to copy and paste this out

Jim

Comment: +1 but the original question used "OR"s between each of the city, firstname, lastname, country...

Comment: Ok, this almost works. If I use AND then it obviously needs all of the text boxes to have some sort of value in them. When all the values are entered, then it will return only the correct customer entered. However, it doesn't allow me for example to just enter "John" and then list only all of the customers who have the first name "John". If I change this to OR then if I enter "John", then his Surname as "Smith", City as Southampton and County as Hampshire then it will list everyone called John, who has the surname "Smith" etc. Eg I get "Dave Smith" too because "Smith" was entered as a surname.

Comment: Perhaps the most problematic of these is if I for example enter Hampshire and then have everyone from Hampshire listed. That means to find the person whose first name I searched for, I must then go through all of the people in Hampshire.

Comment: Hmm, I've also noticed that this solution removes the functionality to enter for example everyone who has a name beginning with "J", if you were to type "Joh" for example then "John" should still be listed.

Comment: Actually, yes, AND is right. I have changed it to this and now it works :D (For some reason I can't post the "@" symbol so I have removed them).    

((FirstName LIKE FirstName + '%') or (isnull(FirstName ,0) FirstName)) AND
   ((Surname LIKE Surname + '%') or (isnull(Surname ,0) = Surname)) AND
   ((City LIKE City + '%') or (isnull(City ,0) = City)) AND
   ((County LIKE County + '%') or (isnull(County,0) = @County))

Answer (score 7):

```
(FirstName LIKE '%' + @FirstName + '%' OR @FirstName IS NULL )
```

Comment: @Brad How do you figure? If FirstName is NULL it will include all possible firstnames. If FirstName is '' then it will pull in everything where "FirstName Like '%%'" which also pulls everything in. In order to screw it up they'd have to type a space. You LTRIM(RTRIM()) the FirstName to compensate for this, but this is correct.

Comment: rescinded! (oh wait...can't change vote at this point unless there's an edit, sorry)

Answer (score 2):

So you only want to consider `@FirstName` if it has a value?  You can do that by changing

```
FirstName LIKE '%' + @FirstName + '%'
```

to this

```
(@FirstName = '' OR FirstName LIKE '%' + @FirstName + '%')
```

or of course if @FirstName is coming in as null instead of empty string, then it would be

```
(@FirstName IS NULL OR FirstName LIKE '%' + @FirstName + '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's more cumbersome, but depending on the size of your dataset and your indexes you can get some performance gains by going this route.

```
Declare @FirstName Nvarchar(10),
        @SurName Nvarchar(10),
        @City Nvarchar(10),
        @County Nvarchar(10),
        @SQL Nvarchar(Max),
        @OrCriteria Nvarchar(Max) = ''

Set     @SQL = 'Select  Column Names
                From    TableName '

If      @FirstName Is Not Null
Begin
        Set     @OrCriteria = @OrCriteria + 'FirstName Like ''%''' + @FirstName + '''%'' Or '
End         

If      @Surname Is Not Null
Begin
        Set     @OrCriteria = @OrCriteria + 'Surname Like ''%''' + @Surname + '''%'' Or '
End     

If      @City Is Not Null
Begin
        Set     @OrCriteria = @OrCriteria + 'City Like ''%''' + @City + '''%'' Or '
End     

If      @County Is Not Null
Begin
        Set     @OrCriteria = @OrCriteria + 'County Like ''%''' + @County + '''%'' Or '
End         

If      @OrCriteria <> ''
Begin
        Set     @SQL = @SQL + 'Where (' + Left(@OrCriteria,Len(@OrCriteria)-4) + ')'
End

Exec    sp_executeSQL @SQL
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't really understand this as it seems complicated to me but I get the same error as Brad's solution.

Comment: That is strange that you receive errors when declaring variables. It works in SSMS so it must be the location/method you're using. I understand not using it though if it doesn't make sense to you. The reason it is beneficial is because it technically has a performance increase over the other solutions because you are only including the columns you need in the where criteria. With this solution if @FirstName is Null you don't run logic against the column to check it because it is assumed they should all be included.

Comment: This method can be very useful when creating large complex queries with multiple tables. For example, if you have a criteria variable that requires a join to another large table, but you technically don't need that table other than as a culling method. If you have a scenario like this where you may on occasion not need that variable you can use dynamic SQL to build the query in such a way that you avoid the join to that table altogether. I've had success substantially improving the performance of some queries using this method. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @sql as varchar(300)
, @FirstName as varchar(50)
, @Surname as varchar(50)
, @City as varchar(50)
, @County as varchar(50)

set  @FirstName = 'myname'
set  @Surname = 'mylastname'
set  @City = null
set  @County = 'county'

set @sql= 'SELECT Column_Names
FROM TableName ' +    
 case when rtrim(ltrim(isnull(@FirstName,'') + isnull(@Surname,'') + isnull(@City,'') + isnull(@County,''))) = '' then '' else 'where ' end
 + coalesce('FirstName LIKE ''%' + nullif(@FirstName,'')+ '%'' or ', '') +
        + coalesce('Surname LIKE ''%' + nullif(@Surname,'')+ '%'' or ', '') +
        + coalesce('City LIKE ''%' + nullif(@City,'')+ '%'' or ', '') +
        + coalesce('County LIKE ''%' + nullif(@County,'')+ '%''', '')

    select @sql
```

the content of `@sql` should be

```
SELECT Column_Names  FROM TableName where FirstName LIKE '%myname%' or Surname LIKE %mylastname%' or County LIKE '%county%'
```

Then to use the Dynamic string you've created you'll need to `Exec @Sql`

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'declare'." when I use this :S

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server exists ISNULL()

then

```
SELECT Column Names
FROM TableName
WHERE
        FirstName LIKE '%' + ISNULL((@FirstName, '') + '%'
        OR Surname LIKE '%' + ISNULL((@Surname, '') + '%'
        OR City LIKE '%' + ISNULL((@City, '') + '%'
        OR County LIKE '%' + ISNULL((@County, '') + '%'
```